# How to call api url method so that app reloads every time the app enters from background to foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building an app that loads data from an `API` `URL` to table view cells. Now it makes an `API` call and loads data into cells only when the app launches for the first time. I want to make an `API` call and reload data every single time the app enters from background to foreground.

I tried calling my `setup()` method in following methods in scene delegate file, thinking that these methods are getting called every time the app enters background.

```swift
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
  tableViewController.setup()
  print("sceneWillResignActive")
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
  tableViewController.setup()
  print("sceneWillResignActive")
}
```

The `API` call is a success but the data is not reloading into table view cells.

Here is my actual code this file includes all the table view delegate and data source methods too.

```swift
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     tableView.separatorStyle = .none
     navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

     setup()
 }

 func setup() {
     WebService().getArticles() { articles in
         if let articles = articles {
             self.articleListVM = ArticleListViewModel(articles: articles)
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Please look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an observer for the app coming to the foreground. In `viewdidLoad` add this code:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(willEnterForeground),
  name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
  object: nil
)
```

Then this function will be called when the app comes to the foreground:

```swift
@objc func willEnterForeground() {
    // Your API code here
}
```